# PrototypeJS Bind Form submit and click

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a form.  I bind the form "submit" event to a method.  I also bind the forms container layer to a "click" event method.  My on "submit" routine is never reached.  If I define the on submit from the console the routine is called.  So what is wrong?  A couple of things to note:  1) I perform the event binding after dom:loaded. 2) My layers are hidden on start (not sure if that makes a difference)

Here is my binding routines in an anonymous dom:loaded function:

```
$('edit_billboard').on('click', _console.handleBillboardScreenClick.bind(_console));
$('edit_billboard').down('form').on('submit', _console.handleBillboardSubmit.bind(_console));
```

Thanks, that is all.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to **stop** the forms event propagation. Otherwise your code might not be able to complete before your browser redirects to the action attribute of your form.

```
_console.handleBillboardSubmit = function(event){
    event.stop();
    // stuff
}
```

<sup>If you intent to redirect the client, do it manually by seting the `location.href` after your code hash finished.</sup>

Comment: This is event bubbling, the `click` event on the button fires and then the event bubbles up to the form and fires the `submit` event. Unless your form needs to POST you can change the `location.href` property to redirect the form, or if all things check out, don't stop the event on the submit handler.